# How to stop one Submit button from running the Submit Click function

Tags: javascript

I have page where there are number of `Submit` buttons and a loading gif is displayed when any of the buttons are pressed:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".loader").hide();
    $(".overlay").fadeOut(1000);

    $("[type='submit']").click (function(){
        $(".loader").fadeIn("fast");
        $(".overlay").fadeIn(1000);
    });
}); 
</script>
```

This works well but there is one button that where I do not want the loading gif to be displayed. I have set the Submit to have an ID:

```
<form action ="https://.../csvdownload.php">
    <input type = "submit" value="CSV download" id="noloader">
</form>
```

The php runs in the background and the current page is not actually left from view.

How do get the loader to not be displayed for this `Submit`?

Comment: Does it still need to submit some form, despite not displaying the gif?

Comment: No. It does a download. It could be a button but that would lead to CSS issues. I was just wondering if it is easy to filter out this one in the function.

Comment: How are you starting the download? Does removing the submit type break the functionality?

Comment: @RandoHinn See edit, but the answer has fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `$(...).is()` function to check if the clicked element has the `noloader` id.

```
$("[type='submit']").click (function(){
    // If the clicked element isn't the noloader element
    if(!$(this).is("#noloader")){
        // Display the loader
        $(".loader").fadeIn("fast");
        $(".overlay").fadeIn(1000);
    }
});
```